# Celestial Altium Library does not show symbols or footprints

Tags: altium, library

I tried to install the Celestial Altium Library a few days ago. I was hoping for a large library of components that could allow me to quickly build some prototypes from time to time. This is in Altium 19.1.

What I got was a large library of part numbers (very promising), but I cannot see symbols or footprints. Where there should be symbols / footprints in the Components panel, I see "Symbol is not present" and "Footprint is not present".

I've been searching for answers for a while and don't see many references to the Celestial Altium Library

I'm guessing (hoping?) that I simply did something wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you add the libraries to the project? Are they on the search path? Are they installed?

Comment: I see a bunch of *.schlib and  *pcblib symbol and footprint files and .step bodies.

Comment: "Celestial Altium Library - altium_library.DbLib" is a database. It shows up in "Available File-based Libraries" as Installed and Activated, The path shows up and is correct.
I consider this installed since I can open my Components Panel (place - part), choose a library i.e. "Capacitors - Ceramic - 0603" and I see many components available. 
When I right click and select place, I don't get a component to place.

Answer (score 1):

The solution in my case was to move the .DbLib file downloaded from "portal.altiumlibrary.com" into the folder to where I downloaded the library. In my case, that was C:\altium-library\

[image]

Check to see if you've followed the instructions on the Celestial website.